# Logo Capitalization when written in text

Tags: text, logo

I am looking for subjective opinions on whether or not to match the capitalization of my (nascent) companies logo when writing its name in text.

Our company is called TheCoin, we are building a cryptocurrency called "THE".  Our logo design uses the name THECoin.  I've found in written text, the form "TheCoin" feels easier on the eye - the capitalized version feels a bit shouty.  However, the logo feels a bit weaker (and loses some of the meta-feel from the currency).  I may be biased though as TheCoin is similar to the way we write names in programming.

Your opinion - is it better - inconsistent capitalization, stronger header, or smoother text?

Comment: To throw another suggestion in the mix, why not THEcoin in both logo and text?

Comment: My opinion is, from a marketing standpoint, the name "THE" is a poor choice. It may as well be "A Coin" or "That Coin". Which in turn could refer to **any** coin.

Comment: "TheCoin" or "The Coin" – I would not set the name in uppercase. That would not look great in text paragraphs otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may get flagged as not a good fit here because it's really opinion-based. But here's my take (I'm sure there's more to it than this, but this is what went through my head when I saw it):

When a short word is capitalized, your brain tells you that you might be looking at an anacronym. This is obviously not what you're looking for here. I definitely favor the "TheCoin."

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it got flagged, but your opinion (and reasoning) is pretty valuable so I'm glad I got it before the gates shut :-)

Comment: After all, the OP is looking for subjective opinions

Comment: @nocturns2 Whether or not the OP is seeking something that's off-topic is irrelevant to it being off-topic or not :)

Answer (score 6):

There's also the issue… not *too* bad in this particular instance - that capitalising all of the first word plus the first letter of the second will make people read it as THEC  oin.

To pick another just as an example, is this two moods or someone with poor apostrophe skill's advertising campaign?

HAPPYSad

.. or even, based on the previous sentence TOPick…  to pick or top ick?

<sup>I daren't post the worst examples I can think of ;)</sup>